# Scala Type mismatch by division

Tags: scala

I have a noobie question about Scala, but I cannot seem to find a solution. I want to calculate n-th row of Pascal Triangle and write it to an array. Parameter n comes from constructor.

My problem is that I get *type mismatch error; Expected String, actual Int* in `(k+1)` part.

I'd be glad for explanation on what actually happens here.

```
var rowElements = new ArrayBuffer[Int]

def calculate(n: Int, k: Int = 0) : Unit = {
    var element: Int = 1
    for(k <- n){
        rowElements.append(element)
        element = (element * (n-k).toFloat / (k+1).toFloat).toInt
    }
}
```

Comment: If you change `k` in your `for` expression error will go away, but another will show:
`value foreach is not a member of Int`. Did you maybe meant something like this:
`for (x <- 0 to n)` (I used `x` is used instead of `k` to avoid shadowing `k` parameter)

Comment: `n` is an Int, and `for(k <- n)` is actually saying "for every k in n". This would make sense if `n` was a List (or similar), but as it is an Int it will fall over.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik from how I understand algorithm, k should be incremented, so I wanted to do something like `for (int k=0; k<=n; k++)` and then use this k for counting next element. I try to implement this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself

Comment: Ok, I actually fixed it. @JamesWhiteley was right and the loop I think I was looking for was `for(k <- 1 to n)`. Still don't understand why it produced mismatch error

Comment: The compiler probably tried to do some sort of behind-the-scenes implicit conversion (see: [Int + String -> String](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WT4kLbr/0)). I'm not sure though, tbh ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Ok, I see. Thank you for your help :)